# Macro to insert Comment Bubbles in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, visual-basic

I have a problem, and I want to know if a macro can solve it:

I'd like a macro that can go through a Microsoft Word document, find every occurrence of a text string, and then highlight the string and create a comment bubble (the kind you get using "track changes") that contains a second text string (e.g., "This seems wrong.").

Can macros insert comment bubbles in that sort of way?

Comment: Did you tried anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just coded this (on Word 2010, though can't see anything that should prevent it working on older versions):

```
Sub CommentBubble()
'
' CommentBubble Macro
'
'
Dim range As range
Set range = ActiveDocument.Content

Do While range.Find.Execute("aaa") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "my comment"
Loop
End Sub
```

Which works, although obviously needs tidying up a bit :)  You could create an Comment object (and specify things like Author, Initals...can't choose the colours though!)